# How to run another JS method from longPolling?

Tags: javascript

How in method with longPolling:

```
    function getNewMessagesLong() {
pollingFishingStarts();
$request = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "listenMessageLong",
    data: lastIncomingMessageLongJson,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        }, complete: getNewMessagesLong})
}
```

on complete to run another method?:

```
function pollingFishingEnds() {
document.getElementById("fishing-end").src = "resources/img/fishing-end.png";
document.getElementById("fishing-start").src = "resources/img/fishing-start-empty.png";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the example you posted, you could simply do something like this, adding an anonymous function that calls your "ends" method AND restarts your polling method:

```
function getNewMessagesLong() {
    pollingFishingStarts();
    $request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "listenMessageLong",
        data: lastIncomingMessageLongJson,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
        }, 
        complete: function() {
            getNewMessagesLong();
            pollingFishingEnds();
        }
    });
}
```

You could also change up to a `window.setInterval()` long-polling paradigm that would allow you to use your `complete` option to set your actual end method, rather than hijacking it for long-polling.

I'm assuming here that you want to call the "end" state code after the first round completion.  Otherwise, there's literally no end to your polling, unless you have some server message to terminate, in which case you need to post that code for additional information.

Comment: Thank you. So can I run another method on_start this ajax query?

Comment: I solve my problem, thx.) So tell me please also how to start any method when this ajax method start?

Comment: @dmitrygolubeu - You could use https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/ to register an event handler for **any** ajax method start.  If you just want to call a function when this ajax method begins, put it inside the getNewMessagesLong function